AuthorizationHeader is empty in Waffle after update to Spring Boot 3
We use Waffle in our Vaadin app. I have debugged the source code for Waffle.
request.getHeader("Authorization");

is called on line 61 in the Waffle-class AuthorizationHeader. This returns null, which causes no WindowsPrincipal being created. This makes it impossible to being authenticated. How can this be solved? This is my code:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint;
    
        @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
            requests.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated();
            })
            .headers(headers -> headers
                .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions
                        .sameOrigin()
                )
            )
            .addFilterAfter(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable); 

        return http.build();

    }


Don't add additional code, configuration, stacktaces etc. as comments, edity our question instead.

The SecurityConfig class for Spring Security needs to be according to the latest demos from the official Waffle github site:
https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/tree/master/Source/JNA/waffle-demo/waffle-spring-boot-filter3/src/main/java/waffle/spring/boot/demo
So the filterChain methods should be:
 http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling(handling -> handling.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint));
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
return http.build();

Authorizationheader will then be filled as needed. Some things ( for instance which requests are authorized) can be changed according to what is needed.
This line of code is only needed for Vaadin apps, since Vaadin has built-in Cross-Site Request Forgery.
 http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

